# Using R-Portable: what directory is used to access static csv files

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I've been looking for a way to share an R app across a few private computers so I was looking at the following link on R-Portable:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/

I was able to follow the instructions and launch the app. The interface pops up and then I see that my visualizations show that no objects are appearing. Part of my app relies on server connections and that data comes through. But other stuff is in static tables for now aka csv files. Below is an example of the shiny log error file:

```
              Warning: Error in subset: object 'car_data' not found
              Stack trace (innermost first):
               71: subset
               70: inherits  [C:\Users\john\Desktop\copydist\TestApp\shiny\/server.R#13]
               69: as.widget
               68: func
               67: output$stops_per_day
               1: shiny::runApp
```

I'm not sure where these should be dumped in order for R-Portable to read them in. The program runs perfectly until it hits read.csv in which case it apparently doesn't find the object. Anyone know the proper folder within R Portable to drop the data? Based on the guy's instructions in the link im not sure what the default directory is.

Appreciate the help guys

Comment: Put the files in an R package and then make sure that package is installed on R-Portable. Then you can access it with `system.file`. That's one idea

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using my package, RInno, which I developed after reading the same article.

To get started:

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
RInno::install_inno()
```

Then you just need to call two functions to create an installation framework in `app_dir`, which should be the directory with your ui.R and server.R and `app_dir/data/.*.csv`:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp")
compile_iss()
```

This will package everything up into an Inno Setup installation wizard in a directory called "RInno_installer".

Comment: this sounds awesome. I will test it out later today and report back